# One SD card transfers file to PC faster than another one

Tags: sd-card, data-transfer

I have several Sandisk SD cards all rated Class 10. One card transfer files to my computer faster than the others. Specifically I had taken several pictures and used a different card each day.

One 16G card transferred 528 pictures (10.4G) to my computer in 7 minutes.  Other cards took hours. For example, another card transferred 508 pictures (9.8G) in 2-1/2 hours.  The other cards I had (both 16G and 32G) also took over 2 hours to transfer about the same amount of data.

What is causing this behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to SD card speed classes (: [Apparently](https://www.sdcard.org/developers/overview/speed_class/) the class is only for write speed, though I don't know if that explains what you're seeing. Could you try formatting the cards and retrying the speed test to eliminate fragmentation as a possibility (though I suspect fragmentation would only affect write speeds)?

Answer (score 2):

If classes are the same, then my first assumption would be [fragmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computing)) issue. SD cards are typically formatted with FAT file system which suffers from fragmentation if the card is used intensively over a period of time.

If this is true and fragmentation is the problem, then you need to defragment the card. However **do not** use any defragmentation software. This software is designed to defragment hard drives and is relying on loop-based algorithms which will wear your card significantly by performing multiple write operations. What I would recommend is to copy all data to backup storage (HDD for example), then format both cards and copy the data back - this should resolve fragmentation issues (if any).

Here is a very good [article](http://www.lagom.nl/misc/flash_fragmentation.html) where author describes his experiments and proves that fragmentation can decrease SD card performance up to 50 times

Comment: I have very rarely used the card with the faster transfer rate so I can see where fragmentation can be an issue since I use the other cards more often.  Thanks for the links to the article.  Off to do some reading